# Where should cake generated js files from a coffeescript node app go?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm using coffeescript while writing a node js app and use cake watch to compile my js files real time.

That's great to be able to do that - but where should I stick those js files? Right now, I'm saving them right next to their respective coffeescript files, but that just feels awkward...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention I've gotten comfortable with is to put CoffeeScript files in a `src` directory and have "compiled" JavaScript output to a `lib` directory.  Like so:

`package.json`
`lib/mymodule.js`
`src/mymodule.coffee`

If you publish the module to the npm registry, you can just include the resulting `lib` directory, which is conventionally where projects written in JavaScript keep there `.js` files.  This keeps everything consistent.